# Bowling Lab: if-else Ladder

Tags: if-statement, joptionpane

I want to create a lab that can keep track of bowling scores. The input value has to be between 0-10. If the number differs, I want to display "Invalid". However, in my code, if I make consecutive errors, my program won't detect numbers out of the range as "Invalid". How can I code so that the program will make me try again until I put in a possible value?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.*;
public class Driver14
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int totalScore, frame, ball;
      totalScore = 0;
      frame = 1;
      ball = 1;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Welcome to Computer Science Bowling!");
      while(frame<11){
         int score1 = Integer.parseInt(
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Score " + totalScore + "\n" + "Frame " + frame + ", Ball " + ball));
         if(0<=score1 && score1<11){
            totalScore = totalScore + score1;
            ball++;
         }
         else{
            score1 = Integer.parseInt(
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid!\n" + "Score " + totalScore + "\n" + "Frame " + frame + ", Ball " + ball));
            totalScore = totalScore + score1;
            ball++;
         }
         int score2 = Integer.parseInt(
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Score " + totalScore + "\n" + "Frame " + frame + ", Ball " + ball));
         if(0<=score2 && score2<11){
            totalScore = totalScore + score2;
            ball++;
         }
         else{
            score2 = Integer.parseInt(
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Invalid!\n" + "Score " + totalScore + "\n" + "Frame " + frame + ", Ball " + ball));
            totalScore = totalScore + score2;
            ball++;
         }
         frame++;
         ball = 1;
      }
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Finished bowling!\nScore "+ totalScore);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generaly you may use this pattern:

```
public static String askUserForInpute(String message){
    String input = null;
    try {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message);
        if(/*anyLogic*/) // OR any method that throws exception for instance Integer.parseInt(input)
            throw new Exception("YOUR MESSAGE");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //ANY INFO YOU WANT
        output = askUserForInpute(message);
    }
    return input;
}
```

You ask user for input and if input is not right you explicitly or implicitly(by a method) throw an exception then catch it and invoke same method again. This is one of possibilites.